# Sorting nested objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have documents that follow this schema:

```json
{
    _id: String,
    globalXP: {
        xp: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        level: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    },
    guilds: [{ _id: String, xp: Number, level: Number }]
}
```

So basically users have their own global XP and xp based on each guild they are in.

Now I want to make a leaderboard for all the users that have a certain `guildID` in their document.
What's the most efficient way to fetch all the user documents that have the guild `_id` in their guilds array and how do I sort them afterwards?

I know it might be messy as hell but bare with me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understand well, you only need this line of code:

```js
var find = await model.find({"guilds._id":"your_guild_id"}).sort({"globalXP.level":-1})
```

This query will return all documentas where `guilds` array contains the specific `_id` and sort by player level.

In this way the best level will be displayed first.

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TRTguxKpPog) is an example how the query works. Please check if it work as you expected.